# Hidden Markov Model in R - Predict the next observation with RHmm

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models, predict

This is my first post on StackOverflow and I could use a little help... Please forgive me if I am not following the correct posting protocols.

There is another example in the StackOverflow for which I am heavily basing my work off of but I cant quite figure out how to adapt the code. Most importantly, I am looking at the solution to the question provided.

Here is the link:

[Getting the next observation from a HMM gaussian mixture distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644522/getting-the-next-observation-from-a-hmm-gaussian-mixture-distribution)

Some background:

RHmm - version 2.1.0 downloaded from R Forge.

RStudio - 0.98.953

R - 3.0.2 32 bit

I am trying to figure out the following issues with my code:

1. How do I amend the solution from the link above (prediction of the next observation) to work with my Baum-Welch model?
   Ex. hm_model <- HMMFit(obs=TWII_Train, nStates=5)
2. The R / RStudio session aborts when I run the Baum-Welch version of the hm_model <- HMMFit(obs=TWII_Train, dis="MIXTURE", nStates=5, nMixt=4). Can you recreate the error and propose a workaround?

Here is my R code:

```
library(quantmod) 

library(RHmm)

getSymbols("^TWII")

TWII_Subset <- window(TWII, start=as.Date("2012-01-01"), end = as.Date("2013-04-01"))

TWII_Train <- cbind(TWII_Subset$TWII.Close - TWII_Subset$TWII.Open,
                    TWII_Subset$TWII.Volume)


hm_model <- HMMFit(obs=TWII_Train, nStates=5)

VitPath <- viterbi(hm_model, TWII_Train)
```

Comment: The recommended approach to code that produces an unexpected shutdown of an R session is to send the code to the package maintainer.  You should update to the most recent R version and most recent package version first. Type `maintainer("RHmm")` at a console prompt for the email address.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I appreciate the insights. I sent an email to the package author, per your suggestion. I am not sure that the package is being actively maintained because it is not on CRAN at the moment and I have been unable to successfully install the archived versions in R. Is there anything I can do in the meantime to further troubleshoot the package?

Comment: I was able to install with:  `install.packages("~/Downloads/RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source", dependencies=TRUE)`. I don't understand how you can say it crashed your session if you cannot install it???

Comment: The only dependencies listed in the DESCRIPTION  file are 'MASS' and 'nlme' and pretty much everyone should have them.

Comment: Hi Bonded. Thanks for the help. I was able to install the 2.0.3 version(after removing the 2.1.0 version from R Forge and using your code) It also looks like part 2 of the question is now solved. You are the man. Any insights on how to tackle part 1? Thank you so much for everything.

Comment: It appears to me that you should be able to use the earlier solution.

Comment: Any ideas for the final code adaptation? I have tried a couple different variations and each gives me a similar type error. Here is what I am seeing: sum(hm_model$HMM$transMat[last(VitPath$states),]*.colSums((matrix(unlist(hm_model$HMM$distribution$mean),nrow=4,ncol=5)))*(matrix(unlist(hm_model$HMM$distribution$proportion),nrow=4,ncol=5)),m=4,n=5), I receive the following error: Error in .colSums((matrix(unlist(hm_model$HMM$distribution$mean), nrow = 4,  : 
  argument "m" is missing, with no default

Comment: As an FYI, this is the same error I receive when I use the hm_model <- HMMFit(obs=TWII_Train, dis="MIXTURE", nStates=5, nMixt=4) which is the same structure as the example. I am not sure how to resolve the argument "m" is missing piece...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a user of this package and this is not really an answer, but a comment would obscure some of the structures. It appears that the "proportion" value of your model is missing (so the structures are different. The "mean" value looks like this:

```
$ mean   :List of 5
  ..$ : num [1:2] 6.72 3.34e+06
  ..$ : num [1:2] -12.4 2420174.5
  ..$ : num [1:2] -2.4 1832546.5
  ..$ : num [1:2] -10.4 1432636.1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5.02 1.96e+06
```

I also suspect that you should be using 2 and 5 rather than 4 and 5 for m and n. Look at the rest of the model with:

```
str(hm_model)
```